# Cannot convert string to dates

Tags: r, date

Here is my code:

```
   STUDYID COUNTRY SITEID SUBJID   SCRNDT    RANDDT   SCRNFDT TLSAMP SCRNSAMP
 GRTMD101     USA     13 130101 4-Dec-12            7-Dec-12    600     1224
 GRTMD101     USA     13 130102 4-Dec-12           26-Dec-12    600     1224
 GRTMD101     USA     13 130103 4-Dec-12           18-Dec-12    600     1224
 GRTMD101     USA      6  60101 5-Dec-12 18-Dec-12              600     1224
 GRTMD101     USA      5  50101 5-Dec-12           11-Dec-12    600     1224
 GRTMD101     USA     13 130104 6-Dec-12 26-Dec-12              600     1224

a<-read above dataset, sorry I don't know how to post this
subvars<-c("STUDYID","SITEID","SUBJID", "RANDDT")
b<-subset(a[subvars],a$RANDDT!="")
c<-as.Date(b$RANDDT,format="%d-%b-%y")
```

However, R just keeps on giving me all `NAs` in `c`, nothing can be converted.

I don't know why this simple task can't be done.

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: to post your data, use `dput(a)`, I assume you're getting `NA` because your date column is a `factor` (check this using `str(a)`).  Add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to the step when you read the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to convert the `RANDDT` variable:

```
library(lubridate)

a = structure(list(STUDYID = c("GRTMD101", "GRTMD101", "GRTMD101", 
"GRTMD101", "GRTMD101", "GRTMD101"), COUNTRY = c("USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA"), SITEID = c(13L, 13L, 13L, 6L, 5L, 
13L), SUBJID = c(130101L, 130102L, 130103L, 60101L, 50101L, 130104L
), SCRNDT = c("4-Dec-12", "4-Dec-12", "4-Dec-12", "5-Dec-12", 
"5-Dec-12", "6-Dec-12"), RANDDT = c("", "", "", "18-Dec-12", 
"", "26-Dec-12"), SCRNFDT = c("7-Dec-12", "26-Dec-12", "18-Dec-12", 
"", "11-Dec-12", ""), TLSAMP = c(600L, 600L, 600L, 600L, 600L, 
600L), SCRNSAMP = c(1224L, 1224L, 1224L, 1224L, 1224L, 1224L)), .Names = c("STUDYID", 
"COUNTRY", "SITEID", "SUBJID", "SCRNDT", "RANDDT", "SCRNFDT", 
"TLSAMP", "SCRNSAMP"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))


b = a[ a$RANDDT != '', c(1,3,4,6)]

b$RANDDT = dmy(b$RANDDT)
b
```

Comment: I tried your code, R returned that "All formats failed to parse. No formats found. "

Comment: This would suggest that your dates are in day-month-year format. There are different combinations in `lubridate`, e.g. dmy, mdy, ymd, etc. You can alos roll your own or include a list of different formats using `parse_date_time()`. This help file has lots of good examples.

Comment: you know what, it still gives me error. What was odd was, I could not even parse this: x<-c("01-Jan-13"). It was still saying that all formats failed to parse. I thought it was the issue that my original variable was read as factor, but this x was definitely a string, yet R didn't take it as date. Do you have any idea why this was going on as an issue? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it might be issue with my R. I tried on another machine, it worked. Thanks for letting me know about 'lubridate'